# while loop won't works right in python

Tags: python, string, while-loop, digits

I wrote this code for summing up digits of a number which is bigger than 10 until the result only have one digit and when I try to compile it, it won't even give me an error until I stop it. I want to know what's the problem.

```
number = input()
#sumed_up_digits = result
result = 0

while len(number) != 1:
    for i in number:
        int_i = int(i)
        result = result + int_i

     number = str(result)

print(result)
```

Comment: Try to use a debugger to catch the error. IMO, result is an increasing value, not a decreasing. Therefore if its initial value is longer than 1 character, it will never stop.

Comment: try to put result = 0 between while and for, and instead of result before while put sum = 0, and after for add result to sum, then print sum at the end. Result as you wrote it is cumulative it will include all the previous sums which will continue to increase.

Comment: the problem is when we enter a number greater than 10, we wont get a single digit number!

Comment: so while loop becomes infinite loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
   s=input()
   n=len(s)
   result=0
   for i in range(n-1):
      result=result+int(s[i])
   print(result)
```

This for loop runs from 0th to (n-2)th index of the given string, hence the last digit will not be added to the result. Like for 1245, it will add 1,2 and 4 to result, but **not** 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
number = input()

if len(number) <= 1:
    print(0)

while len(number) > 1:
    number = str(sum(int(i) for i in number))

print(int(number))
```

Of course, you would need to check that the initial input `number` is made of digits...

Answer (score 0):

result is cumulative and include previous sums.
try:

```
number = input()
#sumed_up_digits = sum
sum = 0

while len(number) != 1:
    result = 0
    for i in number:
        int_i = int(i)
        result = result + int_i
    sum = sum + result
    number = str(result)

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is number isn't being shortened so the condition for the loop to stop is never reached.

```
number = input()

result = 0
while len(number) != 1:
    # set digit to last number
    digit = int(number) % 10
    result += digit
    number = number[:-1]

print(result)
```